# Use App Scripts to open form and make a selection

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-forms, penetration-testing

To put this briefly I am testing a Google drive form that will record votes for a school election to ensure that it is secure.

Is there a way to open a form from the shared URL and list/input data? In short, can I write a script to act like a bot that will vote and try to crash the form?

Sample URL: http://docs.google.com/forms/d/RANDOM_STRING/viewform

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Some time around the end of 2014 a change in the Google Forms service invalidated this hack. Look at [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet/20110656#20110656) and [How to prefill Google form checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393556/how-to-prefill-google-form-checkboxes/26395487#26395487) for a solution that relies on the Form methods.

---

A Google Form, when shown as a "live form", is just an HTML Form, with all the regular behaviors of a form. You can view the HTML source of a live form, and get the information that will help you simulate POST requests.

#### HTML Form

For example, look at the form from [Spreadsheet Email Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778433/spreadsheet-email-trigger/13871541#13871541). Here is the form HTML, cleaned up for readability:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=#FORMKEY#&amp;ifq"

 method="POST" id="ss-form">

  <br>
  <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0">First Name
    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
  </label>
  <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_0"></label>
  <input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_0">
  <br>
  <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_1">No of User
    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
  </label>
  <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_1"></label>
  <select name="entry.1.single" id="entry_1">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_2">Email ID
    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
  </label>
  <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="entry.2.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_2">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="backupCache" value="">


  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <div class="password-warning">Never submit passwords through Google Forms.</div>
</form>
```

Important elements are marked in this screenshot:

[image: Form HTML]

#### Script to simulate a Google Form submission

Armed with the action URL and field names, we can code a function to programmatically submit a form, by modifying the example from [the UrlFetch documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
// Simulate POST to form
function sendHttpPost() {

  // Copy the entire URL from <form action>
  var formAction = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=#FORMKEY#&amp;ifq";

  var payload = {
    "entry.0.single": "Nelson",            // First Name
    "entry.1.single": "10",                // No of users
    "entry.2.single": "user@example.com"   // Email ID
  };

  // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
  // an HTML form. (We do not need to specify contentType; it will
  // automatically default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  // or 'multipart/form-data')

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formAction, options);
}
```

#### Result

Here's the result of the above script, a form response has been added to the spreadsheet.

[image: Screenshot]