# How to prefill Google form checkboxes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have looked at the question "[Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet)" and the code provided in the answer (thanks Mogsdad) works well for text type Google form questions. My question is:
Is it possible to prefill a checkbox type Google form question?

For example, if I have an existing spreadsheet with an entry for "Names" and one of the entries is "Fred, Barney" would it be possible, via coding, to have a form prefill with the checkboxes ticked for "Fred" and "Barney" under a "Names" checkbox type Google form question?

Thanks,
Greig

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The basic pattern for each response can be repeated for most other types. For example, this works for multiple choice:

```js
            item = items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem();
            var respItem = item.createResponse(resp);
```

However, a checkbox can be tricky, as it may have one item, multiple items, and even "other" responses. When the response is recorded to your spreadsheet, it will appear as a comma-separated string; when received in a form submission event (e.g. in a trigger function), we get an array (... where all responses are in the first item in the array, in a comma-separated string). The `createResponse()` method for a checkboxItem expects an array of valid choices... so we can provide that with a little javascript magic:

```js
            item = items[i].asCheckboxItem();
            // Response is a CSV string, need array
            var respArray = resp.split(/ *, */);
            var respItem = item.createResponse(respArray);
```

***EDIT:*** Google has a bug with CheckboxItems and MultipleChoiceItems, when used with "Other" options enabled. Those "other" options are allowed, but get rendered incorrectly in the pre-filled URL, and as a result they don't appear in the displayed form. Please see and star [Issue 4454](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4454).

Here's an updated version of the function from [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet/20110656#20110656), updated to handle lists, multiple choice, and checkbox responses. This version is more general, it can adapt to the headings in your spreadsheet. **BONUS:** if you add a column labeled "Prefilled URL", the script will write its generated URLs there.

[image: screenshot]

```js
/**
 * Use Form API to generate pre-filled form URLs
 * 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/26395487/1677912
 */
function evenBetterBuildUrls() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  // Data for pre-fill
  var headers = data[0];                     // Sheet headers == form titles (questions)

  var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();             // Use form attached to sheet
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  var items = form.getItems();
  var urlCol = headers.indexOf("Prefilled URL");   // If there is a column labeled this way, we'll update it

  // Skip headers, then build URLs for each row in Sheet1.
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++ ) {
    Logger.log("Generating pre-filled URL from spreadsheet for row="+row);
    // build a response from spreadsheet info.
    var response = form.createResponse();
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      var ques = items[i].getTitle();           // Get text of question for item
      var quesCol = headers.indexOf(ques);      // Get col index that contains this question
      var resp = ques ? data[row][quesCol] : "";
      var type = items[i].getType().toString();
      Logger.log("Question='"+ques+"', resp='"+resp+"' type:"+type);
      // Need to treat every type of answer as its specific type.
      switch (items[i].getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
          var item = items[i].asTextItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT: 
          item = items[i].asParagraphTextItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item = items[i].asListItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item = items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item = items[i].asCheckboxItem();
          // In a form submission event, resp is an array, containing CSV strings. Join into 1 string.
          // In spreadsheet, just CSV string. Convert to array of separate choices, ready for createResponse().
          if (typeof resp !== 'string')
            resp = resp.join(',');      // Convert array to CSV
          resp = resp.split(/ *, */);   // Convert CSV to array
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
          item = items[i].asDateItem();
          resp = new Date( resp );
          resp.setDate(resp.getDate()+1);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.DATETIME:
          item = items[i].asDateTimeItem();
          resp = new Date( resp );
          break;
        default:
          item = null;  // Not handling DURATION, GRID, IMAGE, PAGE_BREAK, SCALE, SECTION_HEADER, TIME
          break;
      }
      // Add this answer to our pre-filled URL
      if (item) {
      // Checking if there is any value
        if(resp[0].length != 0){
          var respItem = item.createResponse(resp);
          response.withItemResponse(respItem);
        }
      }
      // else if we have any other type of response, we'll skip it
      else Logger.log("Skipping i="+i+", question="+ques+" type:"+type);
    }
    // Generate the pre-filled URL for this row
    var editResponseUrl = response.toPrefilledUrl();
    // If there is a "Prefilled URL" column, update it
    if (urlCol >= 0) {
      var urlRange = sheet.getRange(row+1,urlCol+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mogsdad. I have tried the code by running it as a script on the spreadsheet and got an error: "Invalid response submitted to item" applying to line 64 (var respItem = item.createResponse(resp);) which is two lines below the comment "// Add this answer to our pre-filled URL". Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tried this on a smaller spreadsheet similar to the example given by Mogsdad and it worked fine. It would seem the problem is in my existing form and spreadsheet. I have an entry in the csv cell that matches to a checkbox but no corresponding check box for it to select when it is going into the form.

Comment: @Greig - the documentation for [CheckboxItem.createResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#createResponse(String)) explains this behavior; it "Throws an exception if any value does not match a valid choice for this item", unless your question includes "Other" options.

Comment: Added note about a google bug with CheckboxItem and MultipleChoiceItem, related to "Other".

Comment: Is there a way of skipping blank entries?

Comment: `if (item && resp !== '')...`

Comment: Is it possible to make an HTTP call and get values from there instead of spreadsheet and fill up the form ?

Comment: @Kartik - are you referring to [Pre-populate form answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en)?

Comment: @Mogsdad - I have dates in my pre-filled data and when looking at the logs the resp variable for a date is showing up in the format "Day MMM DD YYY HH:mm:ss Time Zone". I read [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet) that the date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format. When I toggled out the 'resp = new Date( resp );' the log didn't change. Does the date format need adjusting in this code or am I just confused (as usual)? Thanks.

Comment: @Greig: Slightly different topic; that other question is constructing a pre-filled URL as a string, while this one is using the Forms service to generate the same from JavaScript objects. There's no need to format the date here, it gets taken care of for you.

Comment: @Mogsdad - Thanks Mogsdad. Indeed it does. Regardless of how the date looked in the logs it worked just fine when it came to prefilling. (I wasn't seeing this as I had yet another issue with a null response in a checkbox field - which has nothing to do with the code provided).

Comment: Mogsdad: I'm adapting the evenBetterBuildUrls() and in the process I found some changes that could improve it by making it more easy to adopt by newbies. I.E. A very minor change: 'var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();' could (should?) be changed to 'var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();' I'll be bold and edit your code. Other changes that I'm doing is to add Duration, Time and Grid, adding a "switch" and some lines of code to add the capability of import the responses to the form. Also I'm translating the comments to Spanish. P.S. Obviously I will give you the proper attribution :)

Comment: Ups, the change is too small and SO doesn't allow those.

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the form, fill in the values that you want to be pre-filled.

Then get the `pre-filled URL`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the last Script i have developped it work great for me.

### Update and prefield link for google Form.

This script will not turn off as we know the runtime is 6 minute i have make this script work with google form submit trigger and a manual trigger in the function to get the lastrow.

note :

1. you must change all number with your specific cell
2. Specially you must change you form entry in the last row of the script with your own (Take a look at the pic evry input have a fixed unique entry)

---

Comment: Could you include your script in your answer? It would make your answer much better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue in the script provided as the answer.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  // Data for pre-fill
```

The variable data is referencing the active sheet (ss), not the "Form Responses 1" sheet (sheet). This could be intentional but I thought I should highlight it if anyone else is using the same sheet for pre-filling and responses.