# How do I populate checkbox google form responses from another google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I am having trouble with populating checkbox responses into another google form from the google sheet.
Here is my workflow. Someone fills out the [original google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd8P4qbu9AVoQ6UWd83ptZFCdlUahM0q_XjNg5VpHCSDdbD0w/viewform). The responses are filled out into the google sheet.

I want a link for each submitted google form that will pre-populate each row's responses into a [SEPARATE google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeOoSN58NsFxUzRr5wB9aoEfXp57UZU52oFhcJPTm08_GzWqw/viewform). I am specifically having trouble with the checkbox field.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FMmtCQuNl_ijVSKQu_G6eJiPox7wSejJysGn7QZi4-Q/edit?usp=sharing) is the spreadsheet that includes the formula that has no trouble populating the other fields. (editable)

I tried using the substitute function as seen on the formula on the spreadsheet, but that doesn't do the trick. I have also reviewed [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393556/how-to-prefill-google-form-checkboxes) from a previous question to no avail.

Comment: `I have also reviewed this response from a previous question to no avail.` Hi. The answers to [How to prefill Google form checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26393556/1330560) are pretty comprehensive. The answer to your question will not be a formula; it will be a script as this is the only way to pre-populate a Google Form (and make the necessary link). I would have said that your question was a duplicate of this question. Would you please explain what you mean by `to no avail` and how that question doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: I tried using the script and couldn’t get it to work. I should say, though, I only know how to use script a little.

Comment: `I tried using the script and couldn’t get it to work. I should say, though, I only know how to use script a little`. The point is that you DID try - that's good. And everyone has started off knowing "a little about scripting", so that's not a problem. You'll learn more by _trying_ or having someone help you by overcoming a specific problem than if someone just writes a script for you.

Comment: Is this accurate? You have 2 Google Forms for "Student Incidents": Form"A" contains 11 fields/questions, is completed by a user (maybe teacher??) and is linked to a spreadsheet. Form"B" is identical to Form"A" EXCEPT for 4 extra items relating to School Admin. The process is: 1) user submits Form"A"; 2) Form"A" responses passed to spreadsheet; 3) sheets script runs (`onFormSubmit`??) to create a link to populate Form"B" with Form"A" responses. #4) user clicks the link and submits Form"B". There's no indicator to show if/when the Form"B" link has been run.

Comment: `and couldn’t get it to work`. If you look at my answer, you'll see that the answer in "How to prefill Google form checkboxes?" makes some assumptions that don't apply to you. These would have caused quite a bit of head-scratching. OTOH, because Forms"A" and "B" are largely identical, it handles the pre-filling of checkboxes without requiring any extra work.

Comment: Regarding Form"A" vs Form"B". Form"A" automatically collects the email address of the _Form"A" responder_ (saved to Column B-"Email Address"). Form"B" also automatically collects the email address of the _Form"B" responder_. When prefilling Form"B", should Form"B" have an extra question that will display the name of the Form"A" responder?

Comment: I've modified Form "B" so that it adds an extra field that populates the email address that was automatically collected from Form "A."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 Google Forms for "Student Incidents":

- Form"A", containing 11 fields/questions, is completed by a user (maybe teacher??) and is linked to a spreadsheet.
- Form"B" is *identical* to Form"A" EXCEPT for 4 extra questions relating to School Admin.

The process is:

- user submits Form"A";
- Form"A" responses pass to spreadsheet;
- sheets script builds a link to pre-fill Form"B" with Form"A" responses.
- user clicks the link, answers the extra questions and submits Form"B".

Note: there is no indicator to show if/when the Form"B" link has been run.

---

You have a problem understanding how to populate checkboxes in the form ("checkboxes"-type questions allow a user to select multiple options. Form"A" contains two items with checkboxes: "Teacher action prior to writing referral" (7 options) and "Infraction type" (20 options including one user-definable "Other")

StackOverflow question [How to prefill Google form checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26395487/1330560) provides an excellent solution that handles any question type (including checkboxes) with additional user input BUT... this script includes some features that need to be modified for the OP's situation.

- the script is executed manually and processes every response row; the solution should use the `onFormSubmit` trigger and Event Objects to update each submission as it is received.
- the script assumes that spreadsheet data should pre-fill Form"A"; the solution should pre-fill Form"B"
- the script assumes that Form"A" and Form"B" have the same number of questions; Form"B" has an additional 4 questions.

Except for changes to cater for these features, the referenced script is an excellent resource.

---

**CHECK & UPDATE BEFORE EXECUTING THE SCRIPT**

**Spreadsheet**

- Copy the script into the Script Editor of the spreadsheet linked to Form"A"
- In the spreadsheet, on the "Form Responses" Sheet for Form"A",

  - identify the Column that holds responses for the final question,

    - Pre-fill Links will be saved in the next adjacent Column
    - In Row#1 (Headers) of the next adjacent Column, enter "Prefilled URL" as a header value
  - create an installable trigger for the function.

    - "Event type": `on Form submit`

**Script**

- Confirm/enter the name of the "Response sheet" for FormA
- Confirm/enter the FORM ID for Form"B"
- Confirm/enter the number of questions in Form"A"

---

```
/**
 * 
 * Pre-fill answers for Form "B" from answers in From"A"
 * and create hyperlink for Form"B" submission
 * The script should be in the Editor of the sheet linked to Form"A"
 * Create an installable trigger: "Event type": `on Form submit`
 * Line 19: Confirm Response sheet for FormA
 * Line 22: Enter the FORM ID for Form"B"
 * Line 24: Enter the number of questions in Form"A"
 */
function prefillFormB(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
 
  // use Event Objects
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart

  // force script to take data from Form"A"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("<<INSERT SHEET NAME - FORMA RESPONSES >>");

  // reference Form"B"
  var form = FormApp.openById('<<INSERT ID FOR FORMB >>');
  // number of questions in Form "A"
  var itemLength = 3

  // number of columns on Response sheet
  // number of questions on Form"A", plus timestamp plus "Prefilled URL" column
  var colCount = itemLength+2
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the number of columns in the spreadsheet A = "+colCount)

  // build Data array for this submission
  var data = sheet.getRange(editedRow,1,1,colCount).getValues()

  // build Header data array in Row 1
  // Sheet headers == form titles (questions)
  var headerData = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,colCount).getValues()
  var headers = headerData[0];                     

  var items = form.getItems();

  // If there is a column labeled this way, we'll update it
  var urlCol = headers.indexOf("Prefilled URL");   
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: urlCol = "+urlCol)

  // loop through the submission row
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++ ) {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Generating pre-filled URL from spreadsheet for row#:"+editedRow);
    // build a response from spreadsheet info.
    var response = form.createResponse();
    for (var i=0; i<itemLength; i++) {
      var ques = items[i].getTitle();           // Get text of question for item
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", ques= "+ques)
      var quesCol = headers.indexOf(ques);      // Get col index that contains this question
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", quesCol= "+quesCol)
      var resp = ques ? data[row][quesCol] : "";
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", resp= "+resp)
      var type = items[i].getType().toString();
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Question='"+ques+"', resp='"+resp+"' type:"+type);
      // Need to treat every type of answer as its specific type.
      switch (items[i].getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
          var item = items[i].asTextItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT: 
          item = items[i].asParagraphTextItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item = items[i].asListItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item = items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem();
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item = items[i].asCheckboxItem();
          // In a form submission event, resp is an array, containing CSV strings. Join into 1 string.
          // In spreadsheet, just CSV string. Convert to array of separate choices, ready for createResponse().
          if (typeof resp !== 'string')
            resp = resp.join(',');      // Convert array to CSV
          resp = resp.split(/ *, */);   // Convert CSV to array
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
          item = items[i].asDateItem();
          resp = new Date( resp );
          resp.setDate(resp.getDate()+1);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.DATETIME:
          item = items[i].asDateTimeItem();
          resp = new Date( resp );
          break;
        default:
          item = null;  // Not handling DURATION, GRID, IMAGE, PAGE_BREAK, SCALE, SECTION_HEADER, TIME
          break;
      }
      // Add this answer to our pre-filled URL
      if (item) {
      // Checking if there is any value
        if(resp[0].length != 0){
          var respItem = item.createResponse(resp);
          response.withItemResponse(respItem);
        }
      }
      // else if we have any other type of response, we'll skip it
      else Logger.log("Skipping i="+i+", question="+ques+" type:"+type);
    }
    
    // Generate the pre-filled URL for this row
    var editResponseUrl = response.toPrefilledUrl();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the pre-filled url is "+editResponseUrl)
   
    // If there is a "Prefilled URL" column, update it
    if (urlCol >= 0) {
      var urlRange = sheet.getRange(editedRow,urlCol+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the url range = "+sheet.getRange(editedRow,urlCol+1).getA1Notation())
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: wrote the url")
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Form"A"**

[image: formA]

**Spreadsheet"A"**

[image: sheeta]

**Form"B"**

[image: formB]

**Spreadsheet"B"**

[image: sheetb]

Comment: I've inputted the code, and edited the portions that you mentioned. I am getting an error when executed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at prefillFormB(Code:96:20) All modifications are on the google sheet that was shared on original post.

Comment: The problem relates to the "Email Address". Refer my comment/question in question comments "Regarding Form"A" vs Form"B"".

Comment: I have granted full editor permissions. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I hadn't checked my email. I just did. Everything works with your provided script and thorough directions. Thank you so much!

Comment: I’m pleased that you have resolved the problem. Would you consider “accepting” this answer?