# Send an email on edit if a cell contains specfic value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I thought this would be simple, but I can't figure it out.

If someone types "completed" into A1, I want it to send an email to a specific email address.

Initially I set up a "completed" button, but it doesn't work on mobile. So I now just need it to send me an email when someone types in the word "completed".

Answer (score 1):

The operation of an installable edit trigger function for sending an email is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27277585/1677912). You simply need to tweak that function to focus on the cell or range you're interested in, and have it build & send the email you want.

```js
function installableOnEdit( e ) {
  if (!e) throw new Error( "Need event parameter." ); // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067

  var changedCell = e.range;
  var row = changedCell.getRow();
  var col = changedCell.getColumn();

  // check if change was in A1
  if (row===1 && col===1
      && e.value.toString().match(/completed/i)) // case-insensitive check

    var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  // send to owner
    MailApp.sendEmail( recipient, "Task Completed", "Cell A1 says: "+e.value );

  }
}
```